# Signature verification on CSR always returns false (even if signature is valid)

Tags: signature, pki, verify

Can someone please help me with the following :)

This post relates to an initial post I created at the following URL

[Checking the signature of a CSR (X.509 certificate signing request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41765074/checking-the-signature-of-a-csr-x-509-certificate-signing-request)

However, I wanted to keep this post separate as I am trying an alternative method.

The 'goal' is to 'verify' if a CSR (X509 certificate signing request in PKCS#10 base64 format has a valid signature), meaning take the Public key from the CSR and verify the Signature is OK (e.g. check digest matches after decrypting signature with public key held in certificate, and not just check hash is well formed)

Initially I thought I could simply use the **ChecjSignature** method of the **X509enrollment.CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10** COM object (see my initial post at the above URL)

However contributors to my initial post, pointed out the method I am using (particularly for SHA1 signature verification) would pass even if CSR was not signed or contains a public key not belonging to the signature. In other words it was just confirming the digest (hash) and not the signature was valid.

I should point out I am not a developer but OK with PowerShell and understand the concepts of C#, therefore I did some digging trying to find an appropriate TYPE which had a Method I could use to verify the signature on a CSR, (as I could not find the **KeySignature** method alluded to by a contributor in my original post)

Therefore after some digging, I wrote the following PowerShell code but is always returns FALSE when I know the CSR is valid and signed SHA1

```
<# contents of CSR file 
-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
#>

#get contents of CSR file as a Base64 String (e.g. the -raw parameter returns string rather than array)
$CSR = Get-Content c:\TEMP\csr.txt -raw

#create an instance of the X509enrollment.CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10 class COM object
$RequestComObj = New-Object -ComObject X509enrollment.CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10 

#decode the CSR (returns COM object)
$RequestComObj.InitializeDecode($CSR,6)

#get public key from CSR COM object (returns Base64 string)
$PublicKey = $RequestComObj.PublicKey.EncodedKey()

#get public key from CSR COM object (returns Base64 string)
$Signature = $RequestComObj.Signature()

#convert CSR Base64 string to Byte array
$CSRBytes = [Byte[]][Char[]]$CSR

#convert PublicKey Base64 string to Byte Array
$PublicKeyBytes = [Byte[]][Char[]]$PublicKey

#convert Singature Base64 string to Byte Array 
$SignatureBytes = [Byte[]][Char[]]$Signature

#create an instance of the System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider class
$RSACryptoServiceProvider = [System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider]::Create()

$RSACryptoServiceProvider
#get the OID for the SHA1 algirithm 
$SHA1_OID = [System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig]::MapNameToOID('SHA1')

#attempt to verify signature of CSR
$RSACryptoServiceProvider.VerifyData($CSRBytes,$SHA1_OID,$SignatureBytes)
```

reading the MSDN article on the **System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider** TYPE it states the **VerifyData** method is used to verify data which was signed using the **SignData** method, therefore, I am thinking the reason my code always returns FALSE may be because the CSR was not signed using this **SignData** method in the first instance, but rather some other method.

Therefore can someone kindly help me, and show me how to verfy the signature on a CSR is valid e.g. use the public key in the CSR to check the signature is valid (e.g. decrypt signature with public key, and compare hashes)

Thanks all in advance
__AUser

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to comment on all of stuff you are doing in the code, because it is wrong and not necessary at all. [IX509CertificateRequestPkcs10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377505(v=vs.85).aspx) interface contains [CheckSignature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377510(v=vs.85).aspx) which you should use. So, your whole code is four-liner:

```
#get contents of CSR file as a Base64 String (e.g. the -raw parameter returns string rather than array)
$CSR = Get-Content c:\TEMP\csr.txt -raw

#create an instance of the X509enrollment.CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10 class COM object
$RequestComObj = New-Object -ComObject X509enrollment.CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10 
#decode the CSR (returns COM object)
$RequestComObj.InitializeDecode($CSR,6)

#validate signature
$signatureIsValid = $false
try {
    $RequestComObj.CheckSignature(0x1)
    $signatureIsValid = $true
} catch { }
```

`$signatureIsValid` will hold signature validity status.

Comment: Hello Crypt32 and thanks very much for taking the time to reply

Comment: Sorry I meant to add, initially I was using the CheckSignature method but I was informed in a previous post I made here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41765074/checking-the-signature-of-a-csr-x-509-certificate-signing-request  that this would not necessarily check the signature as it allows Null and therefore just a hash rather than a signed hash would also pass as valid, hence I was looking for an alternative (I may have misunderstood) to replies to my previous post.  Can you kindly clarify this for me?  thanks again

Comment: Actually thinking about it (not tried it yet) if you had a CSR that was not signed and you tried to decode with $RequestComObj.InitializeDecode($CSR,6) I assume it would fail decoding as it was not signed and CSRs are meant to be signed, if that is the case then replying on CheckSignature(0x1) is OK. Any way I digress thanks again for your help :)

Comment: `$RequestComObj.InitializeDecode($CSR,6)` will decode both, signed and unsigned requests. When you pass `0x1` flag to `CheckSignature`, it will throw exception if the signature is invalid or is null-signed.